# How to get time duration of last system startup/reboot in OS X programatically?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, boot

How to get time duration of last system startup/reboot in OS X programatically?

I just need to know how fast my OS X reboots.

Answer (score 3):

The following code (derived from the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345786/1187415)
prints the time of the last reboot:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmpx.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    struct utmpx *bp;
    char *ct;

    setutxent_wtmp(0); // 0 = reverse chronological order
    while ((bp = getutxent_wtmp()) != NULL) {
        if (bp->ut_type == BOOT_TIME) {
            ct = ctime(&bp->ut_tv.tv_sec);
            printf("last reboot: %s", ct);
            break;
        }
    };
    endutxent_wtmp();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same as the first line of "last reboot" on the command line.

Comment: I need to know how much time took last boot loading process (e.g. 10 seconds). I don't need to know when it was.

Comment: @Sergio: It seems that I misunderstood your question, sorry about that. - Many OS X services are started on-demand, so it might be difficult to exactly define a "boot duration". - One idea that comes into my mind is that you use the "Apple System Log" API (see "man 3 asl") to find the most recent "reboot" message, and from there the next "loginwindow" message.