# How to get user's last login including the year in C

Tags: c, unix, authentication

I'm trying to write a program that can get the user's last login time. Then I want to do something with the data. E.g. check which user haven't logged in for 90 days.

So I tried using `last` command, this works great. Just that it doesn't display the year. So if I would do the checking on January 2014, how would I know the last login is actually would be on Dec 2013 or Dec 2012?

This is an example of the code:

```
FILE *file1;
extern FILE *popen();
char command[1024];
char *username;
char result[1024];
char buff[1024];

username = "fikrie";
sprintf(command,"last %s",username);
file1 = popen(command, "r");
while(fgets(result, sizeof(result), file1)!=NULL){
   sprintf(buff,"%s",result);
}
pclose(file1);
```

After some googling, I found out there's a -F flag to display the year. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on HP-UX, Solaris. These platform doesn't recognize that flag.

I've also tested to used utmp based from this link [here](http://www.unix.com/emergency-unix-and-linux-support/138430-last-command-year.html) .The problem is this code will fail on Solaris and HP-UX. Seems like ut_tv doesn't exist in utmp struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct utmp *line;
    time_t timestamp;
    utmpname("/var/log/wtmp");
    setutent();
    while( (line = getutent()) != NULL) {
            if (line->ut_type == USER_PROCESS ) {
                    timestamp = line->ut_tv.tv_sec;
                    printf("%s %s", line->ut_user, asctime(localtime(&timestamp)));
            }
    }
    endutent();
    return 0;
}
```

So, is there a way to do a C code that can generally get the last login for all the Unix platform. (Solaris, Redhat/Linux/CentOS, AIX, HP-UX, Ubuntu). 
Seems like when I manage to get it on 1 platform, then it fails on the others.

Comment: On OS X, it is `getutxent_wtmp()`, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/14345786/1187415. Perhaps that works on other platforms as well.

Comment: getutxent_wtmp() seems like not applicable on Solaris 8. I will try to change it to use getutxent(). Seems like there is a ut_tv inside the utmpx structure.