# How a interactive program knows the shell/terminal from which it is launched

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a client program that can be executed in a linux terminal. The client sends this message to the server, and immediately dies once it receives the ack from the server:

```
struct Msg {
  char my_id[16];
};
```

The server just appends this `my_id` to a log file.

The thing is, I want `Msg::my_id` to be the same across the terminal/shell the client is executed from. How would I do this?

Say, I am a Linux user, and open two terminals: terminals X and Y.

I ran my client from X three times, and from Y twice. In that case, what should I add to the client in order for me to see three Xs and two Ys in the server side log file?

One thing I can think of is to take the ppid and send it. Would this always work? If not, what'd be better alternatives?

Comment: Use the `tty` command to get the name of the terminal you're using.

Comment: PPID likely will be a shell running in terminal unless you forced terminal to run your program instead of shell.

Comment: You can get the terminal device (e.g. `/dev/pts/2`, etc..) using `ttyname_r`. That will at least discriminate between the two terminals for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Author,

Proceed based on comment from Barmar.
I thought of sharing:
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #if defined( CYGWIN_NT ) || defined( LINUX )
            #include <iostream>
            using namespace std;
    #else
            #include <iostream.h>
    #endif
    int main()
    {
            // SAMPLE PROGRAM.
            struct Msg
            {
                    char my_id[16];
            };
            Msg obj;
            // I am not handling fork/... other related enhancements/updates at code.
            sprintf( obj.my_id, "%llu", getppid() );
            cout << obj.my_id << "\n";
            sprintf( obj.my_id, "%s", ttyname(STDIN_FILENO) );
            cout << obj.my_id << "\n";
            return 0;
    }
    $ g++ -DCYGWIN_NT getmy_id.cpp  -o ./a.out
    $ ./a.out
    47130
    /dev/pty0
    $ echo $$ current terminal pid
    47130 current terminal pid
We can also achieve the same using:
user's last login:
    [How to get user's last login including the year in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241786/how-to-get-users-last-login-including-the-year-in-c)

Comment: your answers are terrible. Please spend 2 minutes reading the [tour] to understand how this works and learn [how to format in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) which is used in pretty much every tech websites. No one is going to format the post for you

Comment: Hi phuclv, how to send a private message to you at stackoverflow ? I need to discuss more.